# Windows Media Player 11 Burn option disappeared

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, burning

My burn function in WMP 11 has disappeared. The option is still there but when I click the drop down tab the option to burn does not appear. Any solution? Also if necessary can I simply reinstall WMP over my existing program from the Microsoft website? Thanks

Comment: It could be an API-related problem. Maybe you need some burning APIs like NeroAPI or UltraISO. Microsoft has been forced by UE commission to reduce Windows's functions a lot after anti-trust trials. Maybe WMP is simply unable to burn. And if you are running XP rather than Vista/7, it sounds familiar to me.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Media Player is not letting you burn the file, it could be DRM protected.

To quote Microsoft:

> DRM, which stands for digital rights
>   management, is a technology used by
>   content providers, such as online
>   stores, to control how the digital
>   media files you obtain from them are
>   used and distributed. A file that is
>   protected with DRM requires media
>   usage rights to be delivered with the
>   file. The media usage rights define
>   how the protected file can be used.
>   For example, a right may give you the
>   permission to play the file on your
>   computer (a play right), **burn the file
>   to an audio CD (a burn right)**, or sync
>   the file to a portable device (a sync
>   right).

See their article, [Using protected files (DRM)](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/faq/drm.mspx) which is focused on Windows Media Player 10 and 11.

Comment: It is not working with ANY-even CDs I have used before with no problem...

Comment: Maybe it doesn't recognize a burning device. Does your drive work fine in other applications?